# ASP Multiple UpdatePanels with gridviews but only one updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I wish to have 3 gridviews on a single aspx page fed by individual DB queries (displaying static data, no manipulation) and based on a 10 second timer, refresh the tables. I have the code to return the datatables sorted. I can make it update one gridview which is in one of my update panels, but the other two dont render.

Code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="Index" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Admin" %>
<script runat="server" type="text/c#">
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        FullAccessSession.DataSource=GetStatus("FullAccess");
        FullAccessSession.DataBind();

        Label2.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        LimitedAccessSession.DataSource=GetStatus("LimitedStatus");
        LimitedAccessSession.DataBind();

        Label3.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        LogData.DataSource = GetLog() ;
        LogData.DataBind();

    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        FullAccessSession.DataSource=GetStatus("FullAccess");
        FullAccessSession.DataBind();

    }

    protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label3.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        LogData.DataSource = GetLog() ;
        LogData.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        LimitedAccessSession.DataSource=GetStatus("LimitedStatus");
        LimitedAccessSession.DataBind();
    }



</script>
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateFullAccessStatus" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <!--<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>-->
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Full Access Logged In Users"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Panel not refreshed yet."></asp:Label>
                <br />

                <asp:GridView ID="FullAccessSession" runat="server">

                </asp:GridView>
                <br />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateLimitedAccessStatus" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <!--<asp:Timer ID="Timer3" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>-->

                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Limited Access Logged In Users"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Panel not refreshed yet."></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:GridView ID="LimitedAccessSession" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>
                <br />


            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateLog" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <!--<asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer2_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>-->

                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="General Log"></asp:Label>
                <br />

                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Panel not refreshed yet."></asp:Label>
                <asp:GridView ID="LogData" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
</div>
```

I cant work out why one of my update panels are working. As you can see i've tried using the PreRender function as well as (currently commented out) timers. The labels are updating with the current time but only one gridview displays.

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the **script of timer is lost after the post back inside the UpdatePanel** - the solution is **to take it out of the update panel** and use Triggers

Here is an example that I test it and works.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="2800"></asp:Timer>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" ontick="Timer2_Tick" Interval="2500"></asp:Timer>

<div>
    <div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1"  />
        </Triggers>

        <ContentTemplate>                   
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtTest1"></asp:Literal>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer2"  />
        </Triggers>

        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtTest2"></asp:Literal>
        </ContentTemplate>    
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

and on code behind the `ontick` is the trigger, eg:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTest1.Text += "1.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aristos I have implemented this and it works for a split second then it throws a javascript error from the automatically generated javascript.
I have found the section at fault
    `_endPostBack: function(n, t, i) {
        var r, u, f;
        if (this._request === t.get_webRequest() && (this._processingRequest = !1, this._additionalInput = null, this._request = null), r = this._get_eventHandlerList().getHandler("endRequest"), u = !1, r && (f = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(n, i ? i.dataItems : {}, t), r(this, f), u = f.get_errorHandled()), n && !u) throw n;
    }`

Comment: error is:
`Unhandled exception at line 1, column 123034 in http://localhost:57789/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

its only occurring after the timer ticks over

Comment: Ok, you can ignore my last 2 comments, I think I have fixed this bug. I have this somewhat working. I will look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: This was the crux of the issue, with a few modifications Ive been able to make this work with my scenario. Thanks for your help guys!